# How to access aws s3 current bucketlist content info

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been provided with the access and secret key for an Amazon S3 container. No more details were provided other than to drop some files into some specific folder.

I downloaded Amazon CLI and also the Amazon SDK. So far, seems to be no way for me to check the bucket name or list the folders where I'm supposed to drop my files. Every single command seems to require the knowledge of a bucket name.

Trying to list with `aws s3 ls` gives me the error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Is there a way to list the content of my current location (I'm guessing the credentials I was given are linked directly to a bucket?). I'd like to see at least the folders where I'm supposed to drop my files, but the SDK client for the console app I'm building seems to always require a bucket name.

Was I provided incomplete info or limited rights?

Comment: If this is not the root account access and secret key then ask the one who provided them to you to please grant permissions for s3 on this account for which these access/secret key are provided

Comment: Have you been given the name of the bucket to use? What specific information were you told?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was just not possible without enhanced rights or with the actual bucketname. I was able to procure both later on from the client and able to complete the task. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the bucket name or not? If you *don't* and you don't have permission to `ListAllMyBuckets` and `GetBucketLocation` on `*` **and** `ListBucket` on the bucket in question, then you can't get the bucket name. That's how it is supposed to work. If you know the bucket, then you can run `aws s3 s3://bucket-name/` to get objects in the bucket.

Note, that S3 buckets don't have the concept of "folder". It's User interface "sugar" to make it look like folders and files. Internally, it's just the key and the object

Comment: Ty, that's exactly the point .. I dont have the bucketname, I guess they forgot to send it or give me the rights to list it.